# How can a FlexLayout be created inside a ScrollView using XAML?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I encountered a problem with XAML Layout creation.

My XAML code is the following:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Achievement_Up.Achievements"
             Title="Achievements">

    <ScrollView Margin="20">

        <FlexLayout Wrap="Wrap"
                    Direction="Row"
                    AlignContent="Start">

            <BoxView Color="black" 
                     HeightRequest="100"
                     WidthRequest="100"/>

            <BoxView Color="Green" 
                     HeightRequest="100"
                     WidthRequest="100"/>

        </FlexLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

My debug output, on the contrary of my expectations, is the following:

[image: Output]

Can anybody clarify for me how these tags works?
I don't really know what am I doing wrong.

Lastly, there's no c# code behind the xaml page.

**EDIT**

I would like to see my two boxes on the top left corner in a row, instead of seeing them in the center/left side of the ScrollView.
Knowing how to handle tags likes ScrollView or FlexLayour works could help me get better at developing .NET MAUI applications.

Comment: I would like to see my two boxes view at the start (on the top left side) of the scroll view but for some reason they're appearing at the center/start of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe you don't need ScrollView? FlexLayout is already capable of scrolling. Nesting two scrollable layouts may cause other problems.
2. Use [`AlignItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.flexlayout.alignitems?view=net-maui-7.0#remarks) instead of `AlignContents`.
3. I suspect the `ScrollView` is getting centered in the ContentPage. Try setting ScrollView's `VerticalOptions="Start"`. OR if you remove ScrollView, set VerticalOptions on the FlexLayout.

Comment: I can't still recognize you with an upvote, but thanks for the explanation. Didn't know actually that FlexLayout give the chance to scroll. And also, i noticed that both ScrollView and FlexLayout together seems cause problems with emulator.